# how to sort the multiple array having condition

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I want to sort array in php based on some conditions 
here is the array

```
 $array = [
    [ "a"  => 4, "b" => 8, "c" => 1 ],
    [ "a"  => 9, "b" => 4, "c" => 0 ],
    [ "a"  => -9, "b" => -4, "c" => 1 ],

];
```

if c=1,it should come first,how can i sort the array like this?
I need to add some additional conditions too..i think the same logic will helps me to add multiple conditions

Comment: Your example array has no valid syntax,plz show real given and real expected data here.

Comment: Ok,i edited the question @-JustOnUnderMillions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by a column of the array by doing something like:

```
<?php
$array = [
    [ "a"  => 4, "b" => 8, "c" => 1 ],
    [ "a"  => 9, "b" => 4, "c" => 0 ],
    [ "a"  => -9, "b" => -4, "c" => 1 ],

];

array_multisort($array, array_column($array,"c"));
print_r($array);
```

This will sort by the column "c".

Comment: Can you please consider my additional question-@apokryfos

Comment: @ubm that's a completely different question to the original one so you should ask a separate question with all necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php, to create your own sorting-logic or you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php, which sorts your array by values.

To get an overview of php sorting functions use this page: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php